# Why does echo include -e when I create a file with it?

Tags: shell

Echo usually doesn't include the -e when I use it. But for some reason it includes it in the file it creates.

This is my echo script:

```
FOLDER=$(zenity --forms --add-entry=repo-folder-name)
cd ~/SM64LBuilder/scripts
echo -e "cd ~/SM64LBuilder/repos \ngit clone $(zenity --forms --add-entry=Github-Clone-Link) \necho \"Please select your baserom\" \ncp \$(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='z64 ROMS (z64) | *.z64' --title=\"Select your baserom.us.z64 ROM\") $FOLDER \ncd $FOLDER \necho \"Would you like patches? [y/n]\" \nread answer \nif [ \$answer = \"y\" ]; then \necho \"How many?\" \nfor i in {1..\$number}; do echo \"Chose a file\" && git apply \$(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='patch files (patch) | *.patch' --title=\"Select your patch file\"); done \nfi \necho \"Starting compilation of $FOLDER...\" \nIN=\$(zenity --list --checklist --title \"Build Flags\" --text \"Flags\" --column \"\" --column \"Options\" True VERSION=us False VERSION=eu False VERSION=jp False VERSION=sh False TARGET_BITS=32 True TARGET_BITS=64 False TARGET_RPI=1 False TARGET_WEB=1 False WINDOWS_BUILD=1 False OSX_BUILD=1 WINDOWS_CONSOLE=1 DEBUG=1 BETTERCAMERA=1 NODRAWINGDISTANCE=1 TEXTURE_FIX=1 EXT_OPTIONS_MENU=1 EXTERNAL_DATA=1 DISCORDRPC=1 TEXTSAVES=1) \nif [ \$1 == \"--jobs\" ]; then \nmake \$(echo \$IN | tr \"|\" \" \") \$2 \nelse \nmake \$(echo \$IN | tr \"|\" \" \") \nfi \necho \"$FOLDER compiled!\"" >> $(zenity --forms --add-entry=script-name).sh
```

For some reason when it creates the .sh file it includes the -e. I've tried many things like removing the -e after the echo, or putting more space between the -e and the first " but nothing has been working. This is the output of the echo:

```
-e cd ~/SM64LBuilder/repos 
git clone link 
echo "Please select your baserom" 
cp $(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='z64 ROMS (z64) | *.z64' --title="Select your baserom.us.z64 ROM") example 
cd example 
echo "Would you like patches? [y/n]" 
read answer 
if [ $answer = "y" ]; then 
echo "How many?" 
for i in {1..$number}; do echo "Chose a file" && git apply $(zenity --file-selection --file-filter='patch files (patch) | *.patch' --title="Select your patch file"); done 
fi 
echo "Starting compilation of example..." 
IN=$(zenity --list --checklist --title "Build Flags" --text "Flags" --column "" --column "Options" True VERSION=us False VERSION=eu False VERSION=jp False VERSION=sh False TARGET_BITS=32 True TARGET_BITS=64 False TARGET_RPI=1 False TARGET_WEB=1 False WINDOWS_BUILD=1 False OSX_BUILD=1 WINDOWS_CONSOLE=1 DEBUG=1 BETTERCAMERA=1 NODRAWINGDISTANCE=1 TEXTURE_FIX=1 EXT_OPTIONS_MENU=1 EXTERNAL_DATA=1 DISCORDRPC=1 TEXTSAVES=1) 
if [ $1 == "--jobs" ]; then 
make $(echo $IN | tr "|" " ") $2 
else 
make $(echo $IN | tr "|" " ") 
fi 
echo "example compiled!"
```

I'm quite new to shell script so if it is something really obvious i'm sorry.

Comment: What shell is running your script, i.e. what is on the `#!` line?  `echo` is usually a shell builtin, and it may be that your usual interactive shell supports `-e` while the shell running your script does not.  For instance, on my Ubuntu machine, `bash` does while `sh` does not, so if your script starts `#! /bin/sh` then `echo` won't recognize `-e` as an option.

Comment: You can perhaps solve it by using `/bin/echo` instead, which ensures that instead of the shell builtin you get the external `echo` command, which probably does support `-e`.

Comment: @NateEldredge my script does not start with #! or /bin/echo. Am I supposed to have that?

Comment: @NateEldredge using /bin/echo worked. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should have a `#!` line, otherwise you don't have much control over which shell runs your script.  There might be another question here on SO with more info.  As for `/bin/echo`, I meant that you should replace `echo` by `/bin/echo` on the problematic line of your script.  Don't put `/bin/echo` on the `#!` ("shebang") line.

Comment: Use `printf` instead of `echo`, and you won't have to worry so much about which shell executes the script.

Comment: "when it creates the .sh file" -- what is "it"? Who is creating that file?

Comment: dash-shell must be the culprit. Just use `echo` instead of `echo -e`.